# Cumulative sum of months past with condition dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, cumulative-sum

I only showing 2 cases which illustrate my problem but real `df` has much more rows. I want to create a new column which counts the months past from the last raise for each id. If the id has two raise , month past from last raise should reset in the second raise again. If the id had only one raise the difference of month past from "last raise" should be against the oldest month present in the `df` for each user (the first row for each user).

If i have a dataframe like this:

```
id   amount         date.  diff_amount.  raise    
 1      200   01/02/2018           NaN       0                        
 1      200.  01/03/2018             0       0
 1      200   01/04/2018             0       0
 1      250.  01/05/2018            50       1
 1      250   01/06/2018             0       0
 1      250   01/07/2018             0       0
 1      250   01/09/2018             0       0
 1      250   01/11/2018             0       0
 1      350   01/12/2018           100       1
 1      250   01/01/2019             0       0
 2      500   01/06/2018           NaN       0
 2      500   01/07/2018             0       0
 2      500   01/06/2018             0       0
 2      550   01/07/2018            50       1
```

expected result:

```
id   amount         date.  diff_amount.  raise     month_from_last_raise 
 1      200   01/02/2018           NaN       0                         0                        
 1      200.  01/03/2018             0       0                         1
 1      200   01/04/2018             0       0                         2
 1      250.  01/05/2018            50       1                         3
 1      250   01/06/2018             0       0                         1
 1      250   01/07/2018             0       0                         2
 1      250   01/09/2018             0       0                         3
 1      250   01/11/2018             0       0                         4
 1      350   01/12/2018           100       1                         5
 1      250   01/01/2019             0       0                         1
 2      500   01/06/2018           NaN       0                         0
 2      500   01/07/2018             0       0                         1
 2      500   01/06/2018             0       0                         2
 2      550   01/07/2018            50       1                         3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but if I understand correctly, I found a solution by keeping track of the cumulative values, then grouping by the id's followed by the cumulative values. The input df should be named "df" and the output df will be named "final_df":

```
# Make a column that cumulatively calculates the sums:
df['cumulative'] = df['raise'].cumsum()

# Group by id
id_group = df.groupby('id')

counter = 0
for each_group in id_group:
    # Group by the cumulative values
    cumulative_group = each_group[1].groupby('cumulative')

    for each_cumulative in cumulative_group:
        # Iterate through each cumulative values
        temp_df = each_cumulative[1]
        # Count the number of months since the last change:
        temp_df['month_from_last_raise'] = list(range(temp_df.shape[0]))
        if counter == 0:
            final_df = temp_df
            counter += 1
        else:
            final_df = final_df.append(temp_df)

final_df.drop('cumulative', axis=1, inplace=True)
```